# MS Access "Invalid Procedure Call" matching first half of email address with email addresses from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm running into a "Invalid Procedure Call" when running the below code on tables in an Access 2010 db but it is working in Access 2000 db.

I didn't write this code, I know it is compairing text before the '@' symbol but I would love to hear an explanation of what the specific syntax I am looking at here does: "Left(Nz(t1.Username,''),InStr(Nz(t1.Username,''),'@')-1) = Left(Nz(t2.email,''),InStr(Nz(t2.email,''),'@')-1)
    ))<>False));"

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.Username AS Email
FROM USERS AS t1
WHERE (((Exists (SELECT * 
            FROM LICENSE AS t2 
            WHERE Left(Nz(t1.Username,''),InStr(Nz(t1.Username,''),'@')-1) = Left(Nz(t2.email,''),InStr(Nz(t2.email,''),'@')-1)
    ))<>False));
```

Comment: After more testing the above code works if the email address is something like a@gmail.com or bob@@smith.com so I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nz(t1.Username,'') returns a blank string ('') if t1.UserName is null.

Now, suppose t1.Username is aa.gmail.com

Then InStr(Nz(t1.Username,''),'@')-1 will be 3 - 1 = 2
so, Left(Nz(t1.Username,''),InStr(Nz(t1.Username,''),'@')-1) will be left('aa.gmail.com', 2) = aa

So, this expression basically extracts the part of the email address before @.

Left(Nz(t2.email,''),InStr(Nz(t2.email,''),'@')-1) is doing the same for t2.email

so the where clause is comparing the part of t1.username before @ to the part of t2.email before @.

**Possible cause of error:** If either t1.Username or t2.email is not of the form something@something, then instr will return 0. So, left(some string, 0) may be throwing the error as the function left is expecting a value >=1 as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in a query to solve my similar problem.

```
Newfield: IIf(InStrRev([pullfield],"@"),Left([pullfield],InStrRev([pullfield],"(")-1),[pullfield])
```

It should split it before the "@" symbol, and if there is no "@" then it just leaves the original contents there.